# How to find the total amount of a column x sorted by another column y?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a list of songs, they contain data such as name, artist, year, streams etc. I'm trying to find the 'year' in which songs got the most 'votes' i.o.w. the year with the highest number of total votes.

I'm pretty new to dataframes, and I know how to find things such as the total votes and sort by certain things, but for this, you need to also group them by year and find the sum, and that's what I'm mainly having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [1, 1, 2, 3, 3], "votes": [2, 4, 1, 5, 2]})
>>> df
   year  votes
0     1      2
1     1      4
2     2      1
3     3      5
4     3      2

>>> df.groupby("year")["votes"].sum()
year
1    6
2    1
3    7
Name: votes, dtype: int64

>>> df.groupby("year")["votes"].sum().idxmax()
3
```